# Can't start Unicorn, Rails and Nginx - no such process error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, unicorn

I followed [Digital Ocean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to setup Unicorn, Rails and Nginx, but cannot start Unicorn. I tried two options:

1. install everything, configure nginx as in tutorial and then manually run

`bundle exec unicorn -E development -c config/unicorn.rb`

2. run unicorn independently by adding the following line to config/unicorn.rb

   `listen 80`

Unicorn won't start in neither case, the message is: master failed to start, check stderr for details.

Stderr.log for unicorn says this: unicorn/http_server.rb:715 - no such process

How to fix that? I tried numerous answers from stack overflow, git and other tutorials but nothing seems to help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it: I had to run unicorn as root. Realized this because of access error later in the log. This is the command to start the unicorn:

```
rvmsudo bundle exec unicorn -E development -c config/unicorn.rb
```

Hope it helps someone.